# BIRT - Dynamically replace Label content

Tags: dynamic, label, birt

I know one can dynamically change the content of a Label by using an Event Handler, and overriding for example the onRender method, for example:

```
    @Override
    public void onRender(ILabelInstance label, IReportContext reportContext) 
                     throws ScriptException {
        label.setText("My text!!");
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work if the label has its Localization TextKey set.

Does anyone already tried to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... found a workaround, just remove the Text Key before setting your own text:

```
 @Override
 public void onRender(ILabelInstance label, IReportContext reportContext) 
                              throws ScriptException {
      label.setTextKey("");
      label.setText("My text!!");
  }
```